# JPA orphanRemoval = true tries to update not delete

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have quite specific situation and tried different scenarios to acheive delete from DB when deleting from java collection.

I've House that has relation OneToMany to Room and Room with relation OneToMany to Bed. But also there is relation OneToMany between House and Bed:

House Entity

```
public class HouHouse implements EntityInt, Serializable {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "HOU_HOUSES_SEQ")
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "house", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    @OrderBy("id")
    private List<HouRoom> rooms;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_house")
    @OrderBy("id")
    private List<HouBed> beds;
...
}
```

Room Entity

```
public class HouRoom implements EntityInt, Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "HOU_ROOMS_SEQ")
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_house", nullable = false)
    private HouHouse house;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinColumn(name="ID_ROOM")
    @OrderBy("id")
    private List<HouBed> beds;
}
```

Bed Entity

```
public class HouBed implements EntityInt, Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "HOU_BEDS_SEQ")
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_room", nullable = false)
    private HouRoom room;

    @NotNull
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_house", nullable = false)
    private HouHouse house;
}
```

In such scenario when I try to do:

```
room.getBeds().remove(bed);
entityManager.merge(room);
entityManager.flush();
```

i get an error:

```
06:28:53,344 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-4) Hibernate: 
06:28:53,344 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-4)     update
06:28:53,345 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-4)         public.HOU_BEDS 
06:28:53,345 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-4)     set
06:28:53,345 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-4)         ID_ROOM=null 
06:28:53,345 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-4)     where
06:28:53,345 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-4)         ID_ROOM=? 
06:28:53,345 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-4)         and id=?

06:28:53,346 WARN  [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-4) SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 23502
06:28:53,346 ERROR [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-4) Zadanie wsadowe 0 update public.HOU_BEDS set ID_ROOM=null where ID_ROOM='20' and id='32' zostało przerwane. Wywołaj getNextException by poznać przyczynę.
06:28:53,346 WARN  [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-4) SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 23502
06:28:53,346 ERROR [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-4) ERROR: null value in column "id_room" violates not-null constraint
06:28:53,346 ERROR [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.BatchingBatch] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-4) HHH000315: Exception executing batch [could not perform addBatch]
06:28:53,346 INFO  [com.i4u.qla.action.house.HouRoomCrud] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-4) Start info here: ERROR: null value in column "id_room" violates not-null constraint
06:28:53,348 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-4) javax.transaction.RollbackException: ARJUNA016053: Could not commit transaction.
```

So - jpa tries to update not null field, not to just delete the row.

The second scenario - if I'll change the Room Entity and beds relation to bidirectional, then it **do nothing** after trying to remove element from beds collection and merging the room. Hibernate doesn't try to delete or update the bed:

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, mappedBy="room")
@OrderBy("id")
private List<HouBed> beds;
```

How to manage it works? Please help. I spent so much time to try any solutions from StackOverflow - but couldnot find any that can help in my situation.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunatelly there is some kind of conflict when entities (list of entities) have more than one parents.

I even removed `orphanRemoval` flag and tried to delete child (bed in my example) manually by

> entityManager.remove(bed);

also without success. JPA didn't try to delete nor update it.

So finally I removed OneToMany relation between house and bed, and left only relation OneToMany between room and bed, and between house and room - and everything started to work (there is a lot of "and", I know, sorry)